# Vue Filter get back elements from an subobject

Tags: vue.js

I have an object that looks like this:

```json
{
   "itemsTasks":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "files":[
            
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "files":[
            
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I want to filter and get only back the files object from the object with a special id:

```js
this.editedIndex = 1
this.editedItem.files =  this.itemsTasks.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.id === this.editedIndex;
})
```

But with this I get back the hole object. How can I now get back only the files part?

***EDIT***

With the help of @Shamsail I have found the solution

```js
this.editedItem.files = getFilesFromItemsTasks(this.editedIndex, this.itemsTasks)

function getFilesFromItemsTasks(index, tasks) {
    let result = tasks.filter((obj) => {
        return obj.id === index
    })
    return result[0].files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use a function for it

```
this.editedIndex = 1
this.editedItem.files =  getFilesFromItemsTasks();

getFilesFromItemsTasks(){
   let result = this.itemsTasks.filter((obj) => {
       return obj.id === this.editedIndex;
   })
   return result.files
}
```